# Error occurred during installation of jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

```
$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1630, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1378, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 159, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 271, in init_settings
    nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1061, in nbextensions_path
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 119, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1630, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1378, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 159, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 271, in init_settings
    nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1061, in nbextensions_path
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 119, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: anyone know about this help me

Comment: How you installed jupyter via pip or apt? Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: i,m using ubuntu 18.04,i use pip3 for installing jupyter

Comment: i want jupyter notebook for python3

Answer (score 0):

In which way have you tried to install jupyter, because it doesn't look like the terminal... (I mean: It would bei very helpful if you tell us which command did you used for installing jupyter, because I can't see any commands)

If you want to Install and use jupyter, you can also install anaconda instead. I have installed it too and it includes jupyter notebook.

Comment: ok, i try to install anaconda for jupyter ,thanx